# How can I write this function only by using recursion in F#?

Tags: function, recursion, f#, mutual-recursion

```
let rec n_cartesian_product = function
    | [] -> [[]]
    | x :: xs ->
      let rest = n_cartesian_product xs 
      List.concat (List.map (fun i -> List.map (fun rs -> i :: rs) rest) x)
```

Hello! I wrote this function but I need to write it without using any `List.*` built-in functions. Since there's an inner function that calls an outer function, I assume I must define two mutually recursive functions.

Defining a concat function seemed easy:

```
let rec list_concat ( lst : 'a list list ) : 'a list =
match lst with 
[]    -> []
|x::xs  -> x @ (list_concat xs)
```

The problem is, I'm stuck at the definition of the functions which yield the argument for concat:

```
let rec fun_i rest =
    match rest with
    [] -> []
    |x::xs -> fun_rs

and fun_rs =
fun_i :: fun_rs
```

I can't seem to devise a proper solution. Can you help me?

edit: for instance, given this input

```
[["A";"a"];["B";"b"];["C";"c"]]
```

I want this output:

```
[["A"; "B"; "C"]; ["A"; "B"; "c"]; ["A"; "b"; "C"]; ["A"; "b"; "c"];
 ["a"; "B"; "C"]; ["a"; "B"; "c"]; ["a"; "b"; "C"]; ["a"; "b"; "c"]]
```

Comment: The easy answer - concat and map are available in the source with recursive definitions

Comment: Where can I find the source for them? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

Comment: Cheers, John Palmer!

Comment: Uhm... the implementation in the source refers to the `Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map` branch, which I can't seem to find. Any hint?

Comment: It is a little messy because of optimization - but is here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N-Cartesian Product**

To define the n cartesian product recursively, the easiest method is just to make recursive definitions of the functions used in your original (non-recursive) example:

```
let rec list_concat lst =
    match lst with 
    |[]    -> []
    |x::xs  -> x @ (list_concat xs)

let rec list_map f lst =
    match lst with
    |[] -> []
    |x::xs -> (f x) :: list_map f xs

let rec n_cartesian_product = 
    function
    | [] -> [[]]
    | x :: xs ->
      let rest = n_cartesian_product xs 
      list_concat (list_map (fun head -> list_map (fun tail -> head :: tail) rest) x)
```

In terms of writing idiomatically in F#, it's best to write using more general functions (like `fold`), rather than making a lot of custom functions with explicit recursion.  So, you could define some additional functions:

```
let list_collect f = list_concat << list_map f

let rec list_fold f acc lst =
    match lst with
    |[] -> acc
    |hd::tl -> list_fold f (f acc hd) tl

let n_cartesian_product_folder rest first = 
    list_collect (fun head -> list_map (fun tail -> head :: tail) rest) first
```

Then we can redefine `n_cartesian_product` simply as:

```
let n_cartesian_product2 lst = list_fold (n_cartesian_product_folder) [[]] lst
```

If we were using F# core library functions (rather than custom recursive implementations) this approach would involve more standard code with less to go wrong.

**Cartesian Product**
(I'll leave this part here since apparently it was useful)

Define a function that takes a list of `'a` and make a list of `'b * 'a` where all of the things of type `'b` are some supplied element `y`.

```
/// take a list of 'a and make a list of (y, 'a)
let rec tuplify y lst =
    match lst with
    |[] -> []
    |x::xs -> (y, x) :: (tuplify y xs)
```

Then define a function that recurses through both my lists, calling `tuplify` on the current element of the first list and the entire second list and concat that with the recursive call to cartesian product.

```
/// cartesian product of two lists
let rec cartesianProduct lst1 lst2 =
    match lst1 with
    |[] -> []
    |x::xs -> tuplify x lst2 @ (cartesianProduct xs lst2)
```

Comment: Thanks TheInnerLight, your solution put me on the right track. However, I need to output a list of lists of _n_ elements rather than tuples.

I achieved it by simply modifying _tuplify_'s last line into `|x::xs -> y :: x :: (tuplify y xs)` and defining a function that drives _cartesianProduct_ function.

`let rec cp (lst : 'a list list) : ( 'a list ) =
    match lst with
    [x]      -> x
    |x::xs  -> cartesianProduct x ( cp xs )`

Comment: The problem now is that `cp [["A";"a"];["B";"b"];["C";"c"]];;` outputs `["A"; "B"; "A"; "C"; "A"; "B"; "A"; "c"; "A"; "b"; "A"; "C"; "A"; "b"; "A";
   "c"; "a"; "B"; "a"; "C"; "a"; "B"; "a"; "c"; "a"; "b"; "a"; "C"; "a"; "b";
   "a"; "c"]` instead of  `[["A"; "B"; "C"]; ["A"; "B"; "c"]; ["A"; "b"; "C"]; ["A"; "b"; "c"];
   ["a"; "B"; "C"]; ["a"; "B"; "c"]; ["a"; "b"; "C"]; ["a"; "b"; "c"]]`

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati I've updated my answer with an n cartesian product solution.

Comment: Brilliant! The definition of `list_map` was much more straightforward than I thought it ought to be. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd like to better understand the logic of this line: `list_concat (list_map (fun i -> list_map (fun rs -> i :: rs) rest) x)`. Is it necessary to use lambda functions in this case? Is this a known pattern? Thank you.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati it could be worth making a function to combine `concat` and `map` , this is the `collect` function.  It will simplify your nesting of functions.

Comment: @AntonMariaPrati I've updated the answer with some details about how you'd probably approach this problem in more typical usage.